# Building a query to retrieve available product colors

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following db structure:

```
products: id, product_id, name, desc, etc...
categories: id, name, slug
product_category: product_id, category_id
product_colors: product_id, color_id
product_sizes: product_id, size_id
colors: id, value, hex
sizes: id, value
```

I also have the route: /category/{slug}, where a user sees all products under a category, with a sidebar for filtering them by price and other categories. What is the best way to retrieve all product colors specifically the products that were loaded under a category, distinct values also, so there won't be duplicate colors.

Query to retrieve products:

```
Product::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($cat_ids) {
        return $q->whereIn('id', $cat_ids);
    })->with(['colors', 'sizes', 'brand'])->get();
```

EDIT:
Retrieving colors and sizes:

```
$sizes = collect($products->pluck('sizes'))->flatten()->pluck('value', 'id');
$colors = collect($products->pluck('colors'))->flatten()->pluck('value', 'id');
```

Product.php:

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_category');
}

public function colors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'product_colors');
}

public function sizes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'product_sizes');
}
```

Category.php

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_category');
}
```

Color.php

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_colors');
}
```

Size.php

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_sizes');
}
```

Comment: Database naming convention: good practice if you change your table name like category_product (IN ALPHABETICAL ORDER).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-collection oriented method:
 loop through the products in a category, calling the color function. Add each result to an array. Once done, remove duplicates.

This will accomplish what you asked, but if you are looking to have the original products still attached to the colors (basically a different returned data structure), you'll need to specify what it should look like.

Comment: I have edited my question with what I think is the answer for what I need, I created 2 separate tables for colors and sizes, and now joining them both with products, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

In your category, assuming you have Many Products under one category

Modify your Category.php (to make more sense)

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_category');
}
```

Get the base collection like this

```
$categories = Categories::with('products')->all();
```

Then you will have all the categories with products

Then you will have a nested collection

```
collection => 
    1 => Category [  // category collection
       products => collection() => [ // the products colection
               colors => collection() // colors collection
           ]
       ]
```

You can access a product using a normal foreach loop.

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{

   // since you already have the relationship setup. you can call the 
   // relationship easily like this.
   foreach($category->products as $product)
   {

      // products model  
      foreach($product->colors as $color)
      {
          // your colors model.
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question with what I think is the answer for what I need, I created 2 separate tables for colors and sizes, and now joining them both with products, what do you think?

Comment: What's your need? I mean to get a product collection with categories?
Speaking of your answer. It's good, but i think you are making it complicated. From what i understand you need this right ? category->product->color ? Right ?

Comment: Yes, categories*->products->colors, you can filter products by multiple categories, then once the products are retrieved I use the flatten and pluck methods to get all colors and sizes. What's complicated about what I did exactly?